# Terminal emulator as Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to implement a GUI with a terminal emulator (NOT a system shell, but I would like to have command history, etc). I have only found QConsole, which is not actively developed anymore. Does such a widget exist? If not, where should I begin in looking at how to create such a widget?

Comment: I suspect the closest thing you are going to find in Qt is the QTextEdit (or if you prefer efficiency over rich-text support, QPlainTextEdit) class.  The rest you would need to implement yourself, on top of that.

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. You can start working on top of QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit/QTextBrowser, a HTML widget (QWebView), or maybe even a QListView. You could also develop the terminal from scratch, basically using QScrollView and a custom QWidget's QPaintEvent, which is the way to go if you want the terminal to behave exactly as you want. As is, the question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow, though.

Answer (score 2):

Check QTerminal .Maybe thats what you are looking for. Else you can emulate a console using QTextEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Lxqt has created such a widget for QTerminal, called qtermwidget. It works well and can be found here: https://github.com/lxde/qtermwidget

Answer (score 0):

I developed a [console](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/packages-swipl-win) for [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), one of the leading Prolog implementations worldwide.

Most of the code is required by the complex multithreading model implemented, so would be useless in less specialized environments. But it's actively developed (compatibly with high stability requirements) even if it appears to stale to 2013. I carry on with implementations in my own [loqt](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt). No so stable, of course...